# osCommerce: Payment module stopped working after PHP update

Tags: php, oscommerce

A friend of mine asked for help with his osCommerce; his web hosting did recently upgrade to PHP 5.3, and as he's running osCommerce 2.2 MS2 he got plenty of error messages.

He decided to hide these until he replaces the whole webshop in a near future, and everything works well in exception of one thing: he can't do any changes in the payment modules. When he change a value it goes back to the previous one.

I've never worked with osCommerce before, so for this reason I hope someone here could get me on track.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not a programming question. Reads like a support request. And even for that it lacks in concrete information.

Comment: Then it would help if you could ask for the information you need. It's difficult to give you something that I'm looking for, in this case the right code snippet. And if I knew where this code snippet is located, this question would be pointless as that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

OSCommerce at 2.2 os not compatible with PHP 5.3, largely with OSCommerce using the deprecated `"ereg_replace"` PHP function and the correct method would be to either roll back to a previous version of PHP until such a time as you can upgrade OSCommerce, or to upgrade OSCommerce now.  here are a couple of links for ["patch"](http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,7394) [solutions](http://svn.oscommerce.com/jira/browse/OSC-999) and for the [correct upgrade path](http://www.oscommerce.com/redirect.php/go,45)

Comment: Yeah, that'd indeed be the most correct ways. He seems to be looking for a fast and temporary solution though, as he's going to replace the e-commerce later on. So upgrading through about 4 different versions would in this case be too much work for so little, if you know what I mean. I'll take a look at those patches, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting error and you just want get rid of the error mesg then use this

```
error_reporting(E_DEPRECATED);
```

but it is strongly recommended you update OSCommerce function that is deprecated that will be a good solution